# How to mobile collapse navbar from Materialize CSS in Svelte?

Tags: mobile, navbar, materialize, svelte

I am trying to use the javascript functions in Materialize CSS in my Svelte Project. I have a navbar which is called in app.svelte. I have called M.AutoInit(); in the script tags of app.svelte as so:

```
<script>
  import "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css";
  import "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js";
  import { Router, Route } from "svelte-routing";
  import { setupI18n, isLocaleLoaded, locale } from "./services/i18n";
  import { derived } from "svelte/store";
  import Home from "./pages/Home.svelte";
  import About from "./pages/About.svelte";
  import Navbar from "./layout/Navbar.svelte";
  $: if (!$isLocaleLoaded) {
    setupI18n({ withLocale: "jp" });
  }

  M.AutoInit();
</script>

{#if $isLocaleLoaded}
  <Router>
    <Navbar />
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
  </Router>
{:else}
  <p>Loading...</p>
{/if}
```

I add the required javascript in my Navbar.svelte file as in the materialize css documentation [here.](https://materializecss.com/navbar.html)

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
    var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems, options);
  });
```

However click the mobile hamburger button does not bring out the side menu.
In addition, browser console says that "options" is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

Hello stackoverflow and svelte community. I have fixed the above issue, and will document my steps here:

In my Navbar.svelte file, I re-wrote the javascript into a function:

```
  function mobileNav() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".sidenav");
    var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems);
  }
```

Then, I bound the function to the mobile hamburger button by adding "on:click={mobileNav}" to the hamburger button, as is possible in svelte! Here it is using the Navbar as in documentation:

```
 <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger" on:click={mobileNav}><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
    <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
    <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
  </ul>
```

In the navbar documentation, the function takes the arguments (elems, options) however removing options fixed the problem entirely.